# Using multiple individual regressions Y~X_i to find the best two combination of predictors

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, error

### Problem Statement

Let's say I have multiple solved OLS regressions of the form $Y \sim X_1$, $Y \sim X_2$, ..., $Y \sim X_n$

I want to find which best *two* combined are the best predictors combined, using MSE as the measure of prediction quality. Such that $Y \sim X_i + X_j$ yields the lowest MSE for all $i, j \in [1,n]$

---

### Approach 1: - Intuition

Now, the intuitive and immediate answer is something along the lines of: "find the two with the least correlation and lowest MSE's, and that will yield a lower MSE".

The problem I'm having with that is formalizing the balance between "lowest MSE's" with "least correlation". If I pick the two lowest MSE's for example, they might be perfectly collinear and that won't help. If I pick the two with the lowest pairwise correlation, how will I know that they are each predictive enough so that their combined MSE's are the lowest?

---

### Approach 2: - Brute Force

This seems straight forward enough: for every $X_i, X_j$, run a regression, calculate MSE, choose the lowest.

---

### Approach 3: - Better way?

Is there some approach out there that solves this in a more rigorous/formal way? Maybe some axiom that says "least correlated pair will always yield lowest MSE, only if something something..."?

I feel like there's some way of figuring this out, but everything I'm thinking of leads me to some pairwise correlation...

Is the best approach just trying out all pairs?

Comment: In general univariate regressions don't tell you how the predictors will work as pairs without additionsl information. It could be the case that a pair of predictors, each individually almost uncorrelated with y will together predict it almost perfectly. One that works pretty well on its own might not look as good in a model with other predictors

Comment: So it's safe to say that running a pair-by-pair regression is the only solution? (If we want to guarantee minimum MSE possible)

Comment: *Only* solution? Well, no, since there's other ways of gaining the same or related information.  e.g. Partial regression plots can show you which variables among those not included in the current regression would be useful. e.g. for $Y$ on $X_1$, plots of the residuals from that against the residuals from regressing $X_i$ on $X_1$ (and calculating the correlation) would indicate which variables best "pair" with $X_1$.  However, that involves doing more univariate regressions than you would bivariate regressions. It gives other information though (it's often used to identify influential points)

Comment: On a related note, if you're interested in picking up *monotonic nonlinearity in relationships* - e.g. in case you might consider transforming - partial residual plots would be a useful thing to use instead. See the wikipedia pages for each. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_regression_plot and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_residual_plot

Comment: I guess I meant "most efficient/easiest" solution  These resources are all great, and partial regression is definitely good to know, thank you